# set bootstrap radio as per given value by server

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to loading data to a page, 
server send a value to browser, for example "male". i did try

```
$("#optGender").val("male");
```

to activated/checked radio button I am Male, but it doesnt works

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-danger active">
                    <input type="radio" name="optGender" value="male" checked=""> I am MALE
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-danger">
                    <input type="radio" name="optGender" value="female"> I am FEMALE
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

$("#optGender").prop('checked',"male");

Answer (score 0):

You have no `id` attribute. Try this

```
$("input[name=optGender][value=male]").prop("checked", true)
```

or

```
$('input[name=opt_gender]').val(['male']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Stafox/8qhfnrxe/1/